# Search a string in sql server database at design time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if there is any way to search a string in whole database while designing (something like searching a string in visual studio entire solution) 
Edit: I mean searching a string in all stored procedures , functions , tables ...
its useful for doing some operations  like updating all stored procedures and functions after changing a column type for some table.

I use microsoft sql server 2008

thanks

Comment: Are you interested in searching fieldnames/tabelnames or data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you need [RedGate SQLSearch tool](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/). This tool is free.

Comment: after SQL Serarch installation you can found the "SQL Search" button on toolbar in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

To look for *code* in the database you can search [sys.sql_modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx) (see example) or use something like [Red Gate SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search) which is free

I assume this is what you mean when you want the design time VS search. Note that database code live in system tables: not in files. Hence this SQL or tool is required.

SQL example:

```
SELECT
   OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FROM
   sys.sql_modules
WHERE
   definition like '%whatever%'
```

Note: syscomments is legacy and splits the definition into nvarchar 4000 chunks thus risking *not* finding what you want. The same applies to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES

Answer (score 0):

Though use case is really not useful, there is no way to search data like that, you must write sql to do so.

If you want to search objects ,there are some free add ins available which can help you search the tables, views, stored procedures and functions using a keyword.

Take a look at:
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/11/20/Free-SQL-Server-tools-that-might-make-your-life-a.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly - you need full-text search in database. It's database dependent, what database engine do you use? For MSSQL have a look at [Full-Text Search (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895179.aspx) and create a script for all database objects. Then use a free text editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to search through the script for the string.